# Proving that a series is not uniform convergent but convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

How would I show that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{y^2}{(1+y^2)^n}$$

converges for all $|y| \leq 1$ but that this does not converge uniformly?

I wrote out the series which is:

$$\frac{y^2}{(1+y^2)} + \frac{y^2}{(1+y^2)^2} + \frac{y^2}{(1+y^2)^3} + ... $$
$$=\frac{y^2}{(1+y^2)}*(1 + \frac{1}{(1+y^2)} + \frac{1}{(1+y^2)^2} + ...)$$

$$=\frac{y^2}{(1+y^2)}*(\frac{1}{1 - (\frac{1}{(1+y^2)})})$$
$$ = 1$$

So this series converges to $1$ by the geometric series, now how would I show that this doesn't converges uniformly? I know the definition of uniform convergence which pretty much says

$\forall \epsilon >0,$ there is an $N > 0$ so $\forall y$ and $n \geq N$ we have $|f_n(y) - f(y)| < \epsilon$

But from this, I can't really think of an $\epsilon$... So how would I really approach this problem?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews For $y = 0$, every term is $0$, so the series converges then.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hmm, might be a stupid question but if $y = 0$ doesn't the series converge to $0$?

Comment: Indeed, @Bob, it does. Now, can you think of a theorem that tells you that hence the convergence cannot be uniform?

Comment: @DanielFischer I can't think of a theorem. But if I were to guess, if $(f_n)$ is Cauchy, then  $(f_n)$ must be uniform. Hence, I should show that this is not Cauchy?

Comment: If $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions, and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, then ...?

Comment: $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Yep, forgot about the numerator. Duh.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the sequence of function $$f_n(y) = \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{y^2}{(1+y^2)^n} = 1 - \dfrac1{(1+y^2)^n}$$
Clearly, $f_n(y) \to 1$. However, not uniformly, since given any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can always find $y \in [-1,1]$ such that $\dfrac1{(1+y^2)^n} > \epsilon$. To be specific, we can choose any $y < \sqrt{\dfrac1{\epsilon^{1/n}}-1}$, if $\epsilon < 1$ and to be any number $y<1$ for $\epsilon \geq 1$.